# Why is ranlib called ranlib?

Tags: linux, unix

I was just wondering specifically where the "ran" comes from in ranlib?

I found something once implying randomization of some nature, but I'm unsure where that fits in with the foremost functionality of adding a table of contents to library archives.

Comment: @random The question is specifically about computer software, of which is listed in the help center. The question is marked as "off topic", but a better home for the question is not suggested, making it difficult to resolve. The question may or may not have a known or exact answer, but yet a plausible and insightful one was given within hours of the question being asked, suggesting this was in fact the correct forum in which to pose the question. "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users," per the help center guidelines... seems like the perfect place for such a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because generating an index for the archive lets you access the library 'randomly'. That is you can go directly to any entry in the archive rather than having to read the whole archive from the beginning searching for the entry.

'Random Access' is a general term used for file I/O for things that let you access parts of a file directly rather than reading the file sequentially from the start. Java, for example, has `RandomAccessFile` for reading files this way.